# Decompress concatenated zlib streams without reading next bytes

Tags: c++, qt, zlib

I have a file i can't modify that is composed of 3 concatenated zlib data.
The data aren't very big (some hundred of kilobytes)
How can i read them ? There is the Qt function`qUncompress()` (edited), but it takes a length as argument and I don't know what is the actual length of the stream.

**Solution 1:** When reading the data through a stream, the code I see for doing that read chunk of data and stop when an error is encountered. The problem is when "reading a fixed chunk of data" will consume that chunk and the stream will be corrupted if the size of the stream si not exactly a multiple of N.

**Pseudocode:**

```
while (no error) {
   read N bytes
   decompress_next(these N bytes)
}

... Here there may be up to N-1 totally skipped bytes...
```

It works when N=1, but I feel like a bit hackery. Is there a better alternative ?

**Solution 2:** Uncompress stream, compress again and get size of first chunk. Go to offset and then read etc... (It should be not applicable when input stream is not writable but it should work in my situation)

I can eventually use a c or c++ library (ideally lightweight) if the code is non-trivial.

This may be not possible and I don't know a lot about zlib algorithm, if it know when stream is ended or just read "stateless" data.

Edit: The utility **zlib-flate** look like to do it for solution #2 so it is apparently possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zlib library directly to accomplish this. Here is some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <array>

std::vector<uint8_t> my_compress(std::string const& in_data)
{
    auto bufsize = compressBound(in_data.size());

    std::vector<uint8_t> outbuf(bufsize);

    auto srcptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const*>(in_data.data());
    size_t destlen = outbuf.size();
    auto result = compress(outbuf.data(), &destlen, srcptr, in_data.size());
    assert(result == Z_OK);

    outbuf.resize(destlen);

    return outbuf;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> generate_concatenated_data()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> outbuf;
    std::vector<std::string> strings =
    {
        "zlib is a widely-used library",
        "remember to check your error returns",
        "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
        "Never tell me the odds."
    };

    for(auto const& s: strings)
    {
        auto compressed = my_compress(s);

        // append each compressed stream to the end of the buffer
        outbuf.insert(end(outbuf), begin(compressed), end(compressed));
    }

    return outbuf;
}

void print_buffer(std::vector<char> const& buf)
{
    std::cout << "buffer contains: ";
    for(char c: buf)
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<uint8_t> concat_data = generate_concatenated_data();


    std::array<uint8_t, 1024> scratch = {}; //scratch buffer for decompressing the data. (size doesn't matter )


    z_stream s{};

    // standard zlib init procedure

    s.zalloc = nullptr;
    s.zfree = nullptr;
    s.opaque = nullptr;
    int init_result = inflateInit(&s);
    // insert error checking here.
    assert(init_result == Z_OK);



    s.next_in = concat_data.data();
    s.avail_in = concat_data.size();

    while(s.avail_in > 0)
    {
        // output destination buffer
        std::vector<char> out_data;


        int inflate_ret = 0;
        while(true)
        {

            s.next_out = scratch.data();
            s.avail_out = scratch.size();
            inflate_ret = inflate(&s, Z_NO_FLUSH);

            //make sure we decoded right
            assert(inflate_ret == Z_OK || inflate_ret == Z_STREAM_END);

            auto bytes_decoded = scratch.size() - s.avail_out;


            // there are definitely more efficient ways to append to a vector.
            for(int i = 0; i < bytes_decoded; i++)
            {
                out_data.push_back(scratch[i]);
            }

            // is this stream done?
            if(inflate_ret == Z_STREAM_END) break;

        }
        assert(inflate_ret == Z_STREAM_END);


        // get ready for the next stream
        auto reset_result = inflateReset(&s);
        assert(reset_result == Z_OK);


        // do something with the data.
        print_buffer(out_data);
    }


    //cleanup
    inflateEnd(&s);
    std::cout << "end.\n";

}
```

You'll get the following output:

```
buffer contains: zlib is a widely-used library
buffer contains: remember to check your error returns
buffer contains: the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
buffer contains: Never tell me the odds.
end.
```

The documentation for the zlib library is available here: https://zlib.net/manual.html